# How to pull html encoding from email data using PHP

Tags: php, mime, email, html-email

I'm working with emails and want to display the html in the browser, I'm not sure how to deal with the encoding.  I want to extract the html to display it in the html browser.  The way I plan on doing this is using an html parser on the entire email parsing the data inbetween the  tags in the html section.  Is there an easier/more efficient way to do this?

Here's text encoding

------=_Part_29856965_540743623.1285814590176
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Here's the html encoding

------=_Part_29856965_540743623.1285814590176
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Comment: I think I just found what I was looking for - MIME email message parser http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3169-PHP-Decode-MIME-e-mail-messages.html

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the ezComponents - Mail component. It has a lot of operations for building and using a MIME

http://ezcomponents.org/docs/tutorials/Mail

Comment: I'm not building, I'm reading an email and trying to extract the body - would this still work?

Comment: yes, you can create a MIME object from the email text. Through that object you can return the encoding - 
http://ezcomponents.org/docs/api/trunk/Mail/ezcMailPart.html#methodgetHeader

Comment: Well, I'm not trying to create a MIME object.  I'm trying to extract the html from the email message in a string format.